# Overhead of 'this' keyword

Tags: java, optimization, code-readability

This seems like it could be a common question but I searched SO and Google and couldn't find quite what I'm looking for:

What is the overhead of calls to the `this` keyword in Java? I know in C++ there is some minimal overhead due to *dereferencing* the current object pointer. Does Java incur the same kind of overhead? Is it less optimal to make multiple calls to `this`. It's mostly a question of readability vs. optimization.

Comment: Most likely it does not matter at all, and you get the same bytecode whether you use `this.` or not. Try disassembling your code with `javap -c`, I would not be surprised if the bytecode is exactly the same when you use `this.` and when you don't.

Comment: Overhead compared to what?  You mean `this.a; this.b; this.c;` vs. `T tmp = this; tmp.a; tmp.b; tmp.c;`?

Comment: `this` isn't an operator. Are you talking about accessing instance variables/methods, or chaining to constructors? If you could give us a concrete example - ideally of "which is more expensive, X or Y" - that would help.

Comment: It is compiled to identical byte code

Comment: @Oli: Compared to not prefixing the instance field and methods with `this.`. It can be inferred from the context. ;)

Comment: Are you comparing local variable access time to instance variable access time, or something else?

Comment: It tends to be interpreted languages where this is an issue rather than compiled languages

Comment: @Jesper I did not know about that ability in Java, thanks I will use it in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None whatsoever. They both produce exactly the same bytecode. For example, this:

```
package test;

public class T {

    int a=0;

    public T() {
        System.out.println(a); //this line
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new T();
    }

}
```

...produces:

```
public class test.T {
  int a;

  public test.T();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: aload_0       
       5: iconst_0      
       6: putfield      #2                  // Field a:I
       9: getstatic     #3                  // Field     java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      12: aload_0       
      13: getfield      #2                  // Field a:I
      16: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
      19: return        

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: new           #5                  // class test/T
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #6                  // Method "<init>":()V
       7: pop           
       8: return        
}
```

...regardless of whether the line marked **this line** uses `a` or `this.a`. (Try it if you like - compile the above code both ways and compare both class files with `javap -c`.) Considering they produce exactly the same bytecode, there's no way there can be differences in performance.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean something like using

```
private String myString;
public void doStringStuff() {
    this.myString xxxxx;
}
```

instead of

```
private String myString;
public void doStringStuff() {
    myString xxxxx;
}
```

then the bytecode will be the same, but it will compile a tiny tiny fraction faster, as the compiler does not need to check through local variables looking for a match.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the same *bytecode* will be generated if you use `this` where you don't really have to.

But sometimes you must use `this` keyword (For example when you have name conflicts):

```
private int a;
public MyClass(int a) {
    this.a = a; //this is a must
}
```

For clarity, I think it's a matter of taste. Some programmers prefer to see it, some don't. Also note that `this` is a *keyword*, not an operator.

Tip: Don't waste time on performance issues for really small things..

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. If you call in class A from method a() to method b(), these are *exactly* the same:

```
public void a()
{
    this.b();
    b();
}
```

The overhead you are talking about is when it dereferences the pointer to the object to read or write variables. Imagine you want to write to class A the classmember  `a`, you would do:

```
A x = new A();
x.a = 3;
```

Here, you encounter the overhead: when writing to `x.a`, it has to find out where that exactly is. To find that out, it has to make the sum of `x` and the offset of the variable `a` inside that class. So, it is probably making a sum like: `x + 0x10`. Now, it can write to the address that corresponds with the sum. That is the overhead you were talking about.